# Upload local file to another server using PHP FTP or CURL

Tags: php, ftp, upload

I tried to upload a local file to an online server.
I created an FTP connection to upload the file, but it didn't work.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
// connect and login to FTP server

$ftp_server     = 'ftp.example.so';
$ftp_user_name  = 'name@example.so';
$ftp_user_pass  = 'password';

$ftp_conn       = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login          = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if($login) {
   echo 'connected<br>'; 

   $local_file = 'file_name.txt';
   $server_dir = 'https://example.so/folder/';

   // upload a file
   if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $server_dir, $local_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
       echo "successfully uploaded $local_file\n";
       exit;
   } else {
       echo "There was a problem while uploading $local_file\n";
       exit;
   }
}
```

After running this, I got

> Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\project\upload.php on line 101

Answer (score 1):

The `$remote_file` argument of [`ftp_put`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) is a **path** to the **file** on the FTP server.

You are passing an **URL** to a **folder**.

If should be like:

```
$remote_file = "/folder/file_name.txt";
```

Answer (score -1):

please check correct path of 'file_name.txt';

Comment: Checked and is located in same folder

Answer (score -1):

Now it works, i changed

```
if($login) {
   echo 'connected<br>'; 

   $local_file = 'file_name.txt';
   // $server_dir = 'https://example.so/folder/'; no need

   // upload a file
   if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $local_file, $local_file, FTP_ASCII)) { // changed
       echo "successfully uploaded $local_file\n";
       exit;
   } else {
       echo "There was a problem while uploading $local_file\n";
       exit;
   }

}
```